# Concentration inequality for a biased random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walk

Consider a biased random walk $(X_s)$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ with the probability of moving to the right equal to $p>1/2$ and the probability of moving to the left equal to $q=1-p$. Here $X_t$ is the position of the walk at time $t$.

> I am wanting to know if a concentration inequality of the form:
> $$\mathbb{P}(|\max_{s\leq t} X_s - X_t|>f(t))<g(t)\,,$$
> where $g(t)\to 0$ as $t\to \infty$, such that the above inequality holds? The goal for me is to be able to say $|\max_{s\leq t} X_s - X_t|\leq f(t)$ with high probability (say as $t\to \infty$, this probability goes to one.). If it does, I am wondering what $f(t), g(t)$ could be?

My attempt: I know that the distribution of $\min_{s\leq t} X_s$ is geometric from [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221731/distribution-of-max-n-ge-0-s-n-random-walk) but I do not know the distribution of $\max_{s\leq t} X_s$. I could try to apply Markov's inequality and say:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(|\max_{s\leq t} X_s - X_t|>f(t)) &\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}|\max_{s\leq t} X_s - X_t|}{f(t)} \\
&\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}|\max_{s\leq t} X_s|+\mathbb{E}|X_t|}{f(t)} \\
&= \frac{h(t) + c_2t}{f(t)} \,,
\end{align*}
where $h(t)=\mathbb{E}|\max_{s\leq t} X_s|, c_2t=\mathbb{E}|X_t|$. So if I know the distribution of $\max X_s$, then I can choose $f(t)$, such that
$$\frac{h(t) + c_2t}{f(t)} \to 0\quad\text{as}\quad t\to \infty\,.$$

But I expect better $f(t),g(t)$ are already known using concentration inequalities more powerful than the Markov's inequality since the biased random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ is a well-studied problem. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Consider the dynamics of $Y_{t} := \max_{s \leq t}X_{s} - X_{t}$...it is not too hard to prove that $Y_{t}$ is a (familiar) random walk on $\{0,1,2,\dots,\}$. Once you establish this, some standard concentration inequalities should be available.